# Primefaces Slider does not call setter

Tags: primefaces

I have a primefaces (version 3.4.2) slider and an inputText for output value of the slider value.
The problem is that a change of the slider update the displayed value of the inputText, but the setter bind to the inputText is not called.

Here is my slider:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">

    <h:head>
        <title>Zinsrechner</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="margin-bottom:10px">
                <p:inputText id="x" value="#{zinsrechner.monatlicherBeitrag}" />
                <p:slider minValue="0" maxValue="150" for="x" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>

    </h:body>

</html>
```

And this is my Setter, which is NOT called:

```
public void setMonatlicherBeitrag( Double beitrag ) {
    monatlicherBeitrag = beitrag;
}
```

The Getter IS called:

```
public Double getMonatlicherBeitrag() {
    return GuiParameter.getSpareinlageProMonat();
}
```

Comment: How is your bean annotated?

Comment: With @ManagedBean( name = "zinsrechner" )
@SessionScoped

Comment: do you submit your form anywhere?

Comment: No I don't. Should I? I'm new to PrimeFaces. Until now I worked only with Richfaces.

Comment: If you want to set the value in your backingbean you have to submit the value to the bean, of course. you can do this via ajax or add some submit-button/link to your form.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adding a `<p:ajax>` inside your Slider will to the trick.

Example:

```
<p:slider minValue="0" maxValue="150" for="x">
    <p:ajax event="slideEnd" process="x" />
</p:slider>
```

Comment: And make sure that the inputText field is not set to readonly!

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem, but in my case the thing was that I was setting the `<p:inputNumber .../>` label as read only. I removed that attribute and everything worked.

Comment: Yes, when the attribute read only is true, the value taken from the slider is not sent.